# How it has been made made possible to set php directives in apache configuration files like httpd.conf and .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, configuration, httpd.conf

I know that **php.ini** is the main configuration file for the PHP settings. The PHP settings are done via the php directives and their values.

I've also heard that many of these php directives can also be set in the **.htaccess** files and **httpd.conf** files.

My question is as the files **.htaccess** and **httpd.conf** are the configuration files for apache web server settings how it has been made possible for them to also set php directives inside them?

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: @NicoHaase : How can we set the php directives in configuration files of apache and have effects of these directives set in PHP code?

Comment: What do you mean by "how"? It's all documented at the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) - which of these parts are unclear?